# How can i fix AWS python event key problem

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have a problem with my AWS python code.

I am trying to send a post request to my code on AWS but I have key problems

My code on AWS

```
    import json
    import random
    
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        name = surname = birthDate = favoriteFilm = password = ""
        indexList = keysArray = []
        setParams(event, name, surname, birthDate, favoriteFilm)
        fillArray(keysArray, name, surname, birthDate, favoriteFilm)
        arrayLength = len(keysArray)
        
        while len(password)<6:
            index = getRandomRangeIndex(arrayLength)
            if index in indexList:
                continue
            password = password + keysArray[index]
            indexList.append(index)
            
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(password)
        }
    
    def setParams(event, name, surname, birthDate, favoriteFilm):
        name = event['first_name']
        surname = event['last_name']
        birthDate = event['d_o_b']
        favoriteFilm = event['favorite_film']
    
    def fillArray(keysArray, name, surname, birthDate, favoriteFilm):
        for names in name.split():
            keysArray.append(names)
        keysArray.append(surname)
        for dates in birthDate.split('-'):
            keysArray.append(dates)
        for films in favoriteFilm.split():
            keysArray.append(films)
    
    def getRandomRangeIndex(arrayLength):
        return random.randint(0, arrayLength-1)
```

My Postman request header

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "d_o_b": "1985-12-04",
    "favorite_film": "Back to the Future"
}
```

My problem log

**[ERROR] KeyError: 'first_name'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/password.py", line 7, in lambda_handler
setParams(event, name, surname, birthDate, favoriteFilm)
File "/var/task/password.py", line 24, in setParams
name = event['first_name']**

I am not able to find any solution. How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using api gateway to expose your lambda to the internet?

Comment: Yes i am using Api Gateway, i am connecting with iam user

Comment: Is it REST api or HTTP api?

Comment: I am using REST API

Comment: Maybe i need json parser
When i wrote directly like this

return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event)
    }


service return like this

"body": "{\r\n    \"first_name\": \"John\",\r\n    \"last_name\": \"Smith\",\r\n    \"d_o_b\": \"1985-12-04\",\r\n    \"favorite_film\": \"Back to the Future\"\r\n}",

Comment: Yes. I'm writing answer for that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit your json though api gateway, the event object that your function receives is different than what you submit. The format is shown in [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format).

In your case the `event` will be something like this:

```
{
    "resource": "/test",
    "path": "/test",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
     #
     # a banch of data removed for length
     #
    "body": "{\n    \"first_name\": \"John\",\n    \"last_name\": \"Smith\",\n    \"d_o_b\": \"1985-12-04\",\n    \"favorite_film\": \"Back to the Future\"\n}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Thus, to get your actual data and you have to parse `body` you can use python's [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). You `body` is not `json` string, thus need to use `ast`:

```
import json
import random
import ast

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # overwrite event to keep using event in later parts of your code     
    event = ast.literal_eval(event['body'])
    
    #....
```

Comment: This solved my json key problem thank you so much

Comment: @Servet No problem. Glad it worked out:-)